# SQL Transform Table columns into another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to transform the table "sris" into these 3 tables {"tbl_student,tbl_records,tbl_subject"} where the data in "sris" table will be distributed to the 3 tables to have that relationship

[SEE DATABASE DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnIEl.png)

Comment: Write three INSERT queries. Other than that, what `sris` table? What have you tried? Writing an INSERT statement isn't hard. Did you encounter any problems? Why post this question at all?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: And no, don't post links to images. Images can't be run and tested. *What is the question?* If you want to ask "How do I insert data to another table" just look for a SQL tutorial or the documentation of INSERT. A valid question would be "How do I order the inserts?"

Comment: i have an existing data from table sris and wanted to transfer that data on the 3 tables

Comment: this site won't allow me to post the image but only with that link

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Pretty basic stuff.

```
SELECT tbl_student INTO tbl_student FROM sris
SELECT tbl_records INTO tbl_records FROM sris
SELECT tbl_subject INTO tbl_subject FROM sris
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
"Insert into Table1(Table1Column1, Table1Column2, Table1Column3)  Select srisColumn1, srisColumn2, srisColumn3  from sris"

"Insert into Table2(Table2Column1, Table2Column2, Table2Column3)  Select srisColumn4, srisColumn5, srisColumn6  from sris"

"Insert into Table3(Table3Column1, Table3Column2, Table3Column3)  Select srisColumn7, srisColumn8, srisColumn9  from sris"
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the ID's of each destination column are `IDENTITY`, this should do it:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_student (
    code,
    name)
SELECT DISTINCT
    code = S.STUDENT_NUMBER,
    name = S.STUDENT_NAME
FROM
    sris AS S

INSERT INTO tbl_subject (
    code,
    units)
SELECT DISTINCT
    code = S.SUBJECT_CODE,
    units = S.UNITS
FROM
    sris AS S

INSERT INTO tbl_record (
    grade,
    remarks,
    semester,
    sy,
    student_id,
    subject_id)
SELECT
    grade = S.FINAL_GRADE,
    remarks = S.REMARKS,
    semester = S.SEMESTER,
    sy = S.SY,
    student_id = T.ID,
    subject_id = U.ID
FROM
    sris AS S
    INNER JOIN tbl_student AS T ON S.STUDENT_NUMBER = T.Code
    INNER JOIN tbl_subject AS U ON S.SUBJECT_CODE = U.Code
```